# Jenkins InvalidArgumentException while running Robot Framework with Chrome

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I get the following error when I try to run the Robot Framework code on Jenkins

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.74)
```

I tried updating my Chrome driver locally because my version of Chrome browser is 115.0.5790.99.

Comment: Have you tried updating the ChromeDriver version of the Jenkins master ?

Comment: i am not sure how to do this. somewhere in the file i am seeing this directory 
```CHROME_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'```

Comment: Check if this directory exists on your Jenkins master then replace the actual `chromedriver` with a compatible one, also ensure that the compatible one has execution rights or it wont run at all (Note: I think you can also change the value of `CHROME_PATH` to the current path of the compatible driver you have)

Comment: As @MarcAgnetti mentioned, you could try updating your chromedriver. There's couple of useful PyPI packages to automate that, for example [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/). You should anyway include your launch arguments into your question so there's a reproducible example of your issue.